# Knock out Array doesn't seem to be correct in UI

Tags: javascript, arrays, model-view-controller, knockout.js

I have a drop down that's dynamically created, when it first get's created it has 9 objects with different properties.  When you click on an option it goes out and grabs more info and in this case gets 3 new objects.  But when it updates it goes from this:

[Initial drop down Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQhIQ.png)

to This:

[Updated List after click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcycP.png)

The objects are updated and when console logged they both look good.  However, it appears to be updating by how many items are in the array

view:

```
@if (Model.SubMenu.Count > 8)
{
    <li style="display:inline;" id="MenuSearch">
        <input id="MenuSearchInput" class="form-control" type="text" style="margin:9px; width:90%" placeholder="Search" data-bind="value: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'">
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li id="MenuSearchItem" role="menuitem" data-bind="foreach: FilteredItems">
        <a data-bind="text: name, click: Inventory.GetDomainFacilities"></a>
    </li>
}
```

ViewModel:

```
(function (i) {
    "use strict";

    var vm = i.ViewModels || (i.ViewModels = {});

    vm.DomainSwitchViewModel = function (menuItem) {
        var self = this;
        var data = menuItem;

        self.query = ko.observable('');

        self.AllMenuItems = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.Update = function (data) {
            var mappedItems = _.map(data, function (item) {
                if (item.FacilityID) {
                    return {
                        id: item.FacilityID,
                        name: item.FacilityName,
                        type: 'Facility',
                        href: '/Home/SwitchDomain?' + 'domainID=' + item.DomainID + 'facilityID=' + item.FacilityID
                    }
                }
                else {
                    return {
                        id: item.DomainID,
                        name: item.Name,
                        type: 'Domain',
                        href: ''
                    }
                }
            })
            self.AllMenuItems(mappedItems);
        };

        self.FilteredItems = ko.computed(function () {
            var allItems = self.AllMenuItems();
            var search = self.query().toLowerCase();
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(allItems, function (item) {
                return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0;
            });
        });

        self.Update(menuItem);
    }
    window.Inventory = i;
})(window.Inventory || {});
```

GetDomainFacilities:

```
i.GetDomainFacilities = function (menuItem) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/InventoryBase/GetDomainFacilities',
        data: { domainID: menuItem.id },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var updatedMenuItem = JSON.parse(data);
            vm.Update(updatedMenuItem);
            ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById("DropDownNavMenus"))
            ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("DropDownNavMenus"));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What does your GetDomainFacilities function look like?

Comment: Added, thanks for helping!

Comment: Not seeing anything yet. When you say the items look good in the console what and when exactly are they getting logged? Have you checked the raw data before the json.parse? What does the json look like?

Comment: why are you doing `ko.cleanNode` and then `ko.applyBindings` ?. i guess you dont need to

Comment: The raw data comes out with 3 items I need, then when parsed you indeed get the 3 objects.  I've logged at all parts of the view model and on the GetFacilities function.  The view model AllMenuItems and FilteredItems show that there are 3 objects in it.  But for some reason the UI looks like it wants to create a option for each object in the array.  So if there were 2 you would get 4 options two of the first and two of the next.  And like the 3 you get 3 of the first, 3 of the 2nd and 3 of the third.

Comment: That was the problem.  The clean node and apply bindings.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for the help!